# Pagination not moving cursor to next page and adding extra page to the display paged set

Tags: java, servlets, pagination, paging

The 1st and 2nd page is working fine:
[image: Page No-1]
[image: Page No-2]

but when its moving to 3rd page then its just changing page number instead of moving the cursor to next page link box:
[image]

Here my code is:

1. Adding page no 5
2. Not moving cursor to the page 3 box/link

This is the required ouput:

```
Previous 1.. 2 **3** 4 Next
```

and when arrive at page 4 then it should display as:

```
Previous 1.. 5 6 **7** 8 Next
```

The suspect code that is not working is:

```
    public static String pageIndex(int currentPage, String url, int lastPage) {
     String page = "";
       if(currentPage == lastPage) {                
            page = lastPageIndex(url, lastPage);
        }
        else {
            page = pageOne(currentPage, url) + pageTwo(currentPage, url) + pageThree(currentPage, url);
        }
    return page;
    }
```

Here is my full code: https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/3PpK5bm5F9/
Here is the project. You can check this code live [HERE](https://www.globalsteelweb.com/servlet/News)

Comment: #1 Try to use github to have a runnable sample of your code, mocking your db and without any credential. #2 Why a re you using java for web development? The most current approachs is to have Java for backend (microservices or rest apis) and some javascript framework for frontend (pure javascript, react, angular, vue, etc)

Comment: @JRichardsz I have updated my question and added live link of the paging project